# HTML & CSS Grid not aligning correctly with RBRACE error in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am remaking my indexes for my website and wanted to use grids. So I tried using grids on Dreamweaver and ran into some problems. The first one is that I have an error that says "Expected RBRACE at line 72, col 53". The second problem is that the grid is not aligning in a 4 by 5 grid with the content inside the grid not sizing properly. The third problem is that the image inside the div is not covering the div with the class name of "inside-box". What is the solution to this problem I am having? PLease help me. Sorry that the code is long. I am also new to Stackoverflow.

I have tried aligning my divs and removing grid-template-columns but they did not work.

Edit: 
Here is the link to my webpage:
http://techteach.us/Web2020/ZWeiJian/Labs/Index.html

```css
/*The CSS for making the grids.*/
.wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(4, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 0.5px;
  grid-row-gap: 75px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
}

/*For each individual box.*/
.box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 20%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

/*Creates the styling of the dropdown box.*/
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/*Makes a dropdown box when hovered over.*/
.inside-box:hover .dropdown-content{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML FILE-->
<div class="wrapper">

   <!--Lab 1-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 1</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>
 
   <!--Lab 2-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 2</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 3-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3> Lab 3</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 4-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 4</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>
</div>
     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 5-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 5</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 6-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 6</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 7-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 7</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 8-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 8</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 9-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 9</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 10-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 10</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 11-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 11</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 12-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 12</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 13-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 13</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 14-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 14</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 15-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 15</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 16-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 16</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 17-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 17</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 18-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 18</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 19-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 19</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

   <!--Lab 20-->
   <!--Each individual box.-->
   <div class="box">

     <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
     <div class="inside-box">

       <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
       <div>
         <img src="">
       </div>

       <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
       <div class="txtBar">
         <h3>Lab 20</h3>
       </div>

       <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <p>Explanation of text.</p>
       </div>

     <!--End of inside box div.-->
     </div>

   <!--End of box div.-->
   </div>

</div>
 <br>
<!--END OF HTML FILE-->
```

I expect it to be in a 4 by 5 grid without errors.

Comment: `minmax(4, 1fr)` --> this invalid, the first number need a unit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem lies in the line below:

```css
/* incorrect */

grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(4, 1fr));
```

`auto-fill` is making the column fill the entire grid area. Replace the line with below instead:

```css
/* Try this instead */

grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
```

I am not sure about the overall intention otherwise, and thus cannot comment about other points. Please elaborate what you're trying to do here.

Also, on a separate note, if you're serious about dev skills, consider other feature-rich code editors like VS Code, Atom, or Sublime.

Comment: I am trying to make a navigation page for my other webpages. I want to have 5 rows and 4 columns of boxes. I tried grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); and I am still having the RBRACE error.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code block into a CodePen, and fixed the `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);` which now looks like this: https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/MMYWpB

I haven't used Dreamweaver in ages, but it seems to be warning about a closing bracket somewhere (`}` or `)`), which I can't find in the copied code.

Comment: grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); worked! :D Thank you for your help. Dreamweaver is still saying there is an RBRACE but in the inspector of Mozilla in rules, there are no errors. I think it is a problem with the program itself now. So i'll just ignore it and continue on programming my index of labs.